# Producers Consumer Problem Questions Using Linux Threads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, mutex

I would like to complete a code that satisfies the conditions below.

1. In this program, there is a variable called integer item_program. There are also consumers and producers. The producer, the consumer, is executed as individual threads. The producer increases the value of the item_count variable.The consumer reduces the value of the item_count variable.
2. The threads of this program are producers (2), producers (3), consumers (1), consumers (2), and consumers (3). The producer (2) increases the value of item_count by 2. Consumer (3) reduces the value of item_count by 3.
3. This program runs for a total of 60 seconds, and the value of item_count is always greater than 0 and smaller than 10.
4. Producers and consumers shall print the following format on the console when increasing or decreasing the value of item_count.

=> [thread id count]: Before count: ?, After count: ?

ex1) [20304 producer (3) ] Before count: 2, After count: 5

ex2) [20355 concealer (2) ] Before count: 5, After count: 3

5. The value of the Before count of the previous output statement and the Before count of the subsequent output statement shall not be the same.

ex) Not to be printed as shown below. (Before count both 200)

$ [20304 producer (3) ] Before count: 200, After count: 203

$ [20355 concealer (2) ] Before count: 200, After count: 201

Now, There are two problems.

**First**, **the code doesn't end**. Only ^C can be typed to finish.

**Second**, 'item_count' of code should always be at least 1 and have a value less than 10. **But sometimes it goes beyond that value**. I think sometimes seems that threads don't work atomicly. So an error occurs. When I run the code I wrote below, there may be no errors, but most errors occur. I want you to tell me why.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <errno.h>

pthread_mutex_t region_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t space_available = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t data_available = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

pthread_t   tid;
int item_count = 0;
int time_count = 0;
main()
{
    pthread_t producer_thread2;
    pthread_t producer_thread3;
    pthread_t consumer_thread1;
    pthread_t consumer_thread2;
    pthread_t consumer_thread3;
    void* producer2();
    void* producer3();
    void* consumer1();
    void* consumer2();
    void* consumer3();

    pthread_create(&producer_thread2, NULL, producer2, NULL);
    pthread_create(&producer_thread3, NULL, producer3, NULL);
    pthread_create(&consumer_thread1, NULL, consumer1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&consumer_thread2, NULL, consumer2, NULL);
    pthread_create(&consumer_thread3, NULL, consumer3, NULL);
    pthread_join(producer_thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(producer_thread3, NULL);
    pthread_join(consumer_thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(consumer_thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(consumer_thread3, NULL);
}

void add_buffer(int i) {
    tid = pthread_self();
    if(item_count + i >= 10)
        printf("error producer(%d)\n",i);
    else
        item_count = item_count + i;
    sleep(1);
    time_count++;
    printf("time: %d\n",time_count);
    printf("[%d producer(%d)] Before count: %d, After count: %d\n", (int)tid, i, item_count - i, item_count);
}

void sub_buffer(int i) {
    tid = pthread_self();
    if(item_count - i <= 0)
        printf("error consumer(%d)\n",i);
    else
        item_count = item_count - i;
    sleep(1);
    time_count++;
    printf("time: %d\n",time_count);
    printf("[%d consumer(%d)] Before count: %d, After count: %d\n", (int)tid, i, item_count + i, item_count);
}

void* producer2()
{
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&region_mutex);
        if(item_count + 2 >= 10) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&space_available, &region_mutex);
        }
        add_buffer(2);
        if (time_count == 60)
            break;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&data_available);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&region_mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* producer3()
{
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&region_mutex);
        if(item_count + 3 >= 10) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&space_available, &region_mutex);
        }
        add_buffer(3);
        if (time_count == 60)
            break;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&data_available);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&region_mutex);

    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* consumer1()
{
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&region_mutex);
        if (item_count - 1 <= 0) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&data_available, &region_mutex);
        }
        sub_buffer(1);
        if (time_count == 60)
            break;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&space_available);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&region_mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void* consumer2()
{
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&region_mutex);
        if (item_count - 2 <= 0) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&data_available, &region_mutex);
        }
        sub_buffer(2);
        if (time_count == 60)
            break;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&space_available);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&region_mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void* consumer3()
{
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&region_mutex);
        if (item_count - 3 <= 0) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&data_available, &region_mutex);
        }
        sub_buffer(3);
        if (time_count == 60)
            break;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&space_available);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&region_mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: you are exiting threads via 'break' without unlocking the mutex. This is probably why it does not exit.

Comment: You're also not using your condition variables correctly. They aren't "state"; they're a *signaling* mechanism; that's *all*. You should manage the state via external predicate data, which is the real reason for the mutex in the first place (to protect the predicate data). Your code doesn't guard whatsoever against spurious wakeups, especially with all those broadcasts.

Comment: Then what should I do to really protect it?

Comment: I suggest that you start with a single consumer/producer pair and figure it out first.